# Extracting hidden html with Python

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am a bit puzzled by the "hidden" html code. If I use the "View Source" function, a section of the html source that I am trying to extract looks like this:

```
<div class="comments_with_more">
  <div id="comments_section">
  </div>
</div>
```

If I use the "Inspect Element" function in Firefox, it shows the additional layers that are hidden from the "View Source" option:

```
<div class="comments_with_more">
  <div id="comments_section">
    <div id="comments">
      (....what I am trying to get to.........)
    </div>
    <script>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am suspecting the script might be what's messing this up. Does anyone know how to get to the hidden code in general or in Python?

Comment: The extra sections are not hidden; they were added by JavaScript. "View Source" shows you the HTML structure as sent by the server, "Inspect Element" shows the *current* HTML structure as it is *right now*, including anything changed by JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use [webkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)'s binding for this, [here](http://webscraping.com/blog/Scraping-JavaScript-webpages-with-webkit/) you can see it in action to do what you need (parse a page with javascript changes already loaded)

Comment: Thanks. I ran the code as is from that webpage, but it seems to return an empty page. The content in the html variable is: PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'<html><head></head><body></body></html>'). Am I missing something? Thanks.